# Asp.net Sending information form page to page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to update my old page with new information from my popupscreen.

What i have tried so far is saving the result in a session

```
Session["Data"] = DLvrijecampingplaatsen.SelectedItem;
```

And then load it back in the old page when it hits Page_Load

```
if (Session["Data"] != null)
{
    LBkiescamping.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["Data"]);
}
```

It works only thing is i first need to autopostback te page from another button on my page. So my question is does someone know a way to postback my main page from my popupscreen?

This way i create my new window on my Reservation.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function newPopup(url)
        {
            popupWindow = window.open(url, 'popUpWindow', 'height=700,width=1500,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes');
        }
</script>
```

Then i call this javascript function by this button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server"  Text="Show Map" ID="Btshowmap" onclientclick="javascript:newPopup('Plattegrond.aspx');"/>
```

In the new Plattegrond.aspx page people can select a camping spot by a DropDownList.

```
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="True" ID="Dlbezettecampingplaats" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Dlbezettecampingplaats_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
```

When the have selected a spot i want to pass this selectedindex of the dropdownlist to my old page Reservering.aspx by pressing a button that wil close send the information toReservering.aspx and close my popupwindow. As is sad i can recevie the information of the box on my Reservering.aspx. But i need to do a postback on Reservering.aspx to show the new information on my page.

So if i press the button on my popupscreen. How can i program this button to postback my Reservering.aspx page that is already open?

Comment: Define 'popupscreen', this could mean many different things. Maybe show the code that creates the popup screen.

Comment: Is your popup just a modal window? If that's the case, can't you work with Javascript to sent the data to your main window?

Comment: how do you display and close popup ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it without using session please use window.opener in jquery in popup window. Try below code via jquery.

**Add below code in Reservation.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Reservation.aspx.cs" Inherits="Web.Reservation" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function newPopup(url) {
            popupWindow = window.open(url, 'popUpWindow', 'height=700,width=1500,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes');
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><asp:Button runat="server"  Text="Show Map" ID="Btshowmap" onclientclick="javascript:newPopup('Plattegrond.aspx');"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Textbox value will be changes</td>
    <td> <asp:TextBox ID="LBkiescamping" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Add below code in Plattegrond.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Plattegrond.aspx.cs" Inherits="Web.Plattegrond" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
              <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $("#Dlbezettecampingplaats").change(function () {
                  //Get the drop down selected item value in variable 
                  var val = $("#DLvrijecampingplaatsen").val();
                  //Set the value of LBkiescamping textbox value  
                  window.opener.document.getElementById("LBkiescamping").value = val;//.$("#LBkiescamping").val(val);
                 //window.close();
              });
          });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td> In Change of  Dlbezettecampingplaats Dropdown LBkiescamping textbox value will change</td>
    <td>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Dlbezettecampingplaats">
          <asp:ListItem Value="Volvo1" Text="Volvo1"> </asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Value="Saab1" Text="Saab1"> </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Mercedes1" Text="Mercedes1"> </asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="Audi1" Text="Audi1"> </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Dropdown DLvrijecampingplaatsen selected value will be display in LBkiescamping textbox</td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DLvrijecampingplaatsen">
          <asp:ListItem Value="Volvo" Text="Volvo"> </asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem Value="Saab" Text="Saab"> </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Mercedes" Text="Mercedes"> </asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="Audi" Text="Audi"> </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what if popup screen is defined in another page ? in this case after closing popup screen, value of `$("#DLvrijecampingplaatsen").val()` will be undefined

Comment: I tried your code but the parent page wont refresh. Its the same like the session. It wil save the value but it only wil be showen when i hit a other button on the page that kiks the autopostback of the page.

Comment: Bart where is your DLvrijecampingplaatsen drop down in Reservation.aspx or Plattegrond.aspx? can you send the aspx code

Comment: I have updated my answer please  try this one. I have updated code  window.opener.document.getElementById("LBkiescamping").value = val;

Comment: my DLvrijecampingplaatsen stands in plattegrond.aspx

Comment: I have tried it again but the parant reservation.aspx dont get the postback. so the label wont change until i press a button?

Comment: yeah,Bart it changed without postback.I have updated the code please review and if you have anything.Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by this java function

```
 window.onunload = refreshParent;
 function refreshParent() 
    {
     window.opener.location.reload();
    }
```

only problem when i get back to my old page firefox give the next message

Om deze pagina te bekijken moet Firefox gegevens verzenden, waardoor elke handeling die eerder werd uitgevoerd (zoals zoeken of online aankopen) zal worden herhaald.

[image: Firefox message]

How can i disable this?

Comment: Once you submit something or did a postback browser will show a window like this. I don't think you can disable this programmatically

Answer (score 0):

instead of using server side code,session. you can do this using javascript code. 
in your page, add javascript function to update lable, which will called from popup page. 
in page1.aspx

```
  function updateLBkiescamping(val){
     document.getElementById('<%= LBkiescamping.ClientID %>').innerText = val;
  }
```

in popup.aspx

```
 function updateParent(){
   var ddl = document.getElementById('<%=DLvrijecampingplaatsen %>'); 
  window.opener.updateLBkiescamping( ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text);
  //if you need close popup
  //window.close();
 }
```

updateParent need to call some button click even in your popup page

```
   <input type="button" value="update" onclick="updateParent();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The best sultion i have found it this one it to use a timmer that checks if the popup windows has been closed en then updates the button.

u still have to use the session to save the new value between the pages.

```
var interval;
    var popupWindow;
    function newPopup(url) {
        popupWindow = window.open(url, 'popUpWindow', 'height=1000,width=1500,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes');
        interval = window.setInterval(function () {
            if (popupWindow == null || popupWindow.closed)
            {
                document.getElementById("refreshMe").click()
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

it works fine only thin thats left is that this refresh triggers my validators on my page so if some feelds are empty the wil show up.

but thanks for al reactions :)